# Prevent R from removing diacritics (UTF-8)

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, rstudio, diacritics

R somehow ignores diacritics when I enter a character string. I am trying to setup utf-8 everywhere possible, but it keeps doing it. How do I make it keep the diacritics?

Example:

```
string <- "Marie Skłodowska-Curie"
string
```

Returns:

```
"Marie Sklodowska-Curie actions"
```

What I need (note the "ł"):

```
"Marie Skłodowska-Curie actions"
```

The same happens when I load a csv in utf-8 encoding and then try to use strings containing the "ł" character. R replaces it with "l".

For context, I am using RStudio.

Comment: Something like this appoach [utf-8 subs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805806/converting-accents-to-utf-8-characters)?

Comment: R on WIndows doesn't handle non-Ascii characters well.  You may need to use Unicode escapes:  `ł` is `\u0142`.  Or read the strings from a file with a declared encoding.  Or use the experimental UTF-8 native version of R, described at https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/05/02/utf-8-support-on-windows/ .